# do I need a nested foreach loop to accomplish this?

Tags: powershell, foreach, nested-loops

Looking at this chunk of code I managed to cobble together:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$hashpath" -Recurse -File | 
Select @{N='FileHash'; E={(Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.FullName -algorithm MD5).Hash}},FullName,Length,LastWriteTime |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.FullName=($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape("$hashpath"), '')
        $_.LastWriteTime=($_.LastWriteTime).ToSTring('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')
        Write-Host "$($count) of $($numfiles)" $_.FileHash $_.FullName $_.Length $_.LastWriteTime
        ++$count
        Write-Output "$($_.Filehash) $($_.FullName) $($_.Length) $($_.LastWriteTime)" } | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders | 
    Out-String -Width 4096 | 
    Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath "$hashlog" -Append
```

As written, it displays the `Write-Host "$($count of $($numfiles)" $_.FileHash $_.FullName $_.Length` AFTER it calculates the file hash. I want it to display it BEFORE it calculates the file hash.

I've tried nesting another `foreach-object` inside, but I can't seem to pass parameters properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify, if you display that BEFORE then `$_.FileHash` is `$null` wouldn't it?

Comment: with two foreach loops you have two $_ variables.  Easy way is to set the outer $_ to a named variable : foreach-Object { $xyz = $_; $xyz.FullName=(

Comment: This ties into the proposal (and linked proposals): [`#19827` `Tee-Object` should have a `-Console` parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19827)

Comment: @iRon Thank you for the links. But I want output to console different from log file.  Answer by mrvzqr worked beautifully.